# Redirect using .htaccess to redirect multiple old pages and non-www to www

Tags: wordpress

I have the following rewrite on my .htaccess file. It works fine but I can't redirect non-www to www. This website also serves as a multi site wordpress installation using sub-domains. So I'm pretty confused on how to have the main site redirect non-www to www links and the page redirections and not mess up the sub domain sites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com\.au
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]

##### PAGE REDIRECTS ######
RewriteRule ^about\_abc\.htm$ "http://www.abc.com.au/company-profile/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must take several steps:

1. Edit the home_url and site_url options for the main sites (in wp_options if your table_prefix is "wp_", as you want to change the urls of your main site).
2. Edit the domain of your main blog in wp_blogs to www.your-domain version
3. Edit wp-config DOMAIN CURRENT SITE like this:

   ```
   define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com'); //your new www one!
   ```
4. Go to wp-admin of your blog and reset permalinks
5. Your RewriteRule is fine, but you can make it more dynamic to use in other sites like this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

Or, if your host multi-domains into the same network, like this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example1|example2|exampleN).com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you set up previously other blogs in your subdomain, you are safe to go, since they are linked to the previous main domain without www. I've tested personally this recipe into a multi-domains network migrated to www main domains last month.